# ElementNSImpl does not work in Eclipse with Java Zulu 11

Tags: java, eclipse, java-11, azul-zulu

## EDIT

I tried to do `gradle build` and it gives me this error:

> package com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom is declared in module java.xml, which does not export it

I inspected `gradle dependencies`, but no one uses `java.xml`

---

We use ElementNSImpl in only one part of our code (I don't know why...). Anyway, when I tried to switch to Java 11 Zulu, Eclipse gives me this error:

> The type com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl is not accessible

With OpenJDK 8 we have to import it using `xerces:xercesImpl:2.6.2-jaxb-1.0.6`

I inspected the class with Eclipse and it's a public class, under the Zulu 11 jar.

Comment: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom is JDK-internal. You should have got a compiler warning with JDK 8 (and older) to warn you about that. Since JDK 9, JDK internals are encapsulated at compile-time so this is why you are getting a compilation error. The right thing is to fix whatever it is that is making direct use of a JDK internal class. You can workaround it temporarily by compiling with `--add-exports java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom=ALL-UNNAMED`.

Comment: When you use an external Xerces lib, the class should be `org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl` (note: without preceding `com.sun.`), but I’m still wondering whether you really need to access that implementation class whose name already bears “*internal*” and “*Impl*”, rather than using the standard DOM API (the `org.w3c.dom.Element` interface).

Comment: @Holger Don't know, we found it in the code, added by someone in the past... anyway Eclipse asked me about `com.sun.org.apache.xerces`. That's why we previously use [xerces version 2.6.2-jaxb-1.0.6](http://central.maven.org/maven2/xerces/xercesImpl/2.6.2-jaxb-1.0.6/xercesImpl-2.6.2-jaxb-1.0.6.jar)

Comment: Then, I’d try whether the code still works when changing that reference to the standard `Element` interface.

Comment: @Holger With `Element` works. If you write an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Holger said in [its comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56061693/elementnsimpl-does-not-work-in-eclipse-with-java-zulu-11#comment98770412_56061693) and @AlanBateman said in [its comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56061693/elementnsimpl-does-not-work-in-eclipse-with-java-zulu-11#comment98770168_56061693),
`com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom` is JDK-internal. You have simply to substitute `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl` with `org.w3c.dom.Element`

Answer (score 0):

In my case changing the import to `org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl` worked. Refer to https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/apiDocs/org/apache/xerces/dom/ElementNSImpl.html

I'm using Red Hat openjdk 11 btw.

Hope it helps.